# Moq: Manipulate passed param does not work

Tags: c#, moq

I have something like this:

```
MyMock
.Setup(m => m.MyMethodAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
.Returns((Stream outStream) =>
{
   outStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is the content"));
   return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

this can be compiled and executed. I can see the debugger running the code. But the caller of this method do not get the value of the Stream. What do i miss?

Edit1:

Change Returns to Callback has the same behavior

```
.Callback((MT365ReceiveResult result, Stream outStream) =>
{
    outStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is the content"));
});
```

Comment: What's the expected signature of `MyMethodAsync`? What it's supposed to take as an argument and what it returns?

Comment: Is the caller using `MyMock.Object`? Sometimes people think Moq intercepts all instances of a Type but it doesn't, you have to work with the mocked instance that you Setup.

Comment: Have you tried using Moq's ReturnsAsync method instead of Returns?

Comment: `outStream` is a variable scoped to the lambda handler, setting it to something is pointless.

Comment: @Guru Stron
Does that mean: It is impossible to test those type of functions with moq? I simply have a function that takes one parameter and the method do manipulate it. The calling code needs the Stream to be filled to continue successfully.

Comment: @MarcelW.: could you answer the question? My guess is you try to misuse moq, however, without an explicit signature of your method I could be wrong.

Comment: @MarcelW. it is not evident from your question what type of function you are trying to test, as you already were asked - what `MyMethodAsync` is supposed to do and what are expectations of the calling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the sample does not use the `Stream` that is provided by the caller of the method, but assigns a new `MemoryStream` to the parameter. As the parameter is not marked with `ref` or `out`, this reassignment is only valid in the method, but not outside.

I suppose, you want to write a value to the `Stream` that is provided by the caller. You can do this with the following code:

```
MyMock
  .Setup(m => m.MyMethodAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
  .Returns((Stream outStream) =>
  {
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is the content");
    outStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  });
```